# JavaScript working on plain HTML but not on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Imagemap resizer js library to help me with responsive maps. It's controled by a small js library from here github dot com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer. It's supposed to help the HTML coords become responsive even when it usually isn't (such as ios Chrome).

To start off testing, I've copied the entire example page from the author of the script into a static html page at
http://www.talesofyore.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/map.htm.
I've used the following code right before the /body:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidjbradshaw.com/imagemap-resizer/js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('map').imageMapResize();
</script>`
As you can see, it creates the html coords properly.

However, when I try adding it to my WordPress theme header, it creates the coords, but they are all located at the same line in the center below the image (i've styled a couple of them with blue border so you can see them . http://www.talesofyore.com/?p=1#comment-1

Here's what I've tried so far:
If I hardcode the code (img code, map code and javascript code) directly after the /head, everything works fine.

However, cases when it doesn't work:
- If I enqueue into my WP by using enqueue

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'imagemapresizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imageMapResizer.min.js', array(), '', true );
```

it adds a version number and messes up, so it doesn't work.
- If I remove the

it doesn't work. I haven't tried enqueing it yet, but I'll cross that bridge later.

But here's what I don't understand.
I've hardcoded the entire code right at the end of header.php and placed it within
    
and in this case, not even the hardcoded version works.

Can anyone give it a look? Thank you!

Comment: Missing some important parts of the question....the code...what that code is supposed to do  ... and what it's doing now beyond *"it doesn't work"*

Comment: Sorry! Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

have you include your script at your functions ?

like this my code:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-js', EL_JS . '/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', null, '1.9.1' ,  true );
```

and you call at html before `</body>` with this `<?php wp_footer() ?>`

Comment: I tried enqueing, it actually adds to the problem, I think because of the version part. But I'll work around that, the issue is somewhere else. I've updated the original post for more clarification.

Comment: OMG, you just gave me an idea that solved it. Since the enqueue was messing up the script, my javascript include was under conditional PHP in the header and I guess that's what was messing it up. Noob, I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check inspect element after page load successfully.Sometimes it's not working due to different version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. ince the enqueue was messing up the script, my javascript include was under conditional PHP in the header and I guess that's what was messing it up. Noob, I know.